# Sorting a Large Excel Spreadsheet by Date - Fails on 3rd Iteration

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

I am new to VBA as a language, and I'm having issues sorting a large spreadsheet. The sheet is roughly 400,000 rows by 8 columns. The relevant data begins on row 5. In Column C, I changed the format of the date and rounded it down to give a single integer representing the day.

The goal is to find where the data changes days, and cut and paste all of that day's data to a seperate tab. The code I have written successfully does this for the first 2 days, but the 3rd iteration and beyond will not work properly. I have used a color code (blue) to represent the last row for each day, and I'm using this color change as my loop condition. The 3rd loop ignores the 1st color change and instead cuts and pastes 2 day's worth of data, and the 4th loop moves 3 days.

Would there be a more efficient way to move each day's data to a new tab? Each day represents 28800 rows by 6 columns. It should be noted that an additional macro is run before this in order to simply organize the raw data. The portion of the code giving me issues are the loops following the "Sort the data by date" comment.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance. Attached is my code and a sample of the data

```
Sub HOBO_Split_v2()

'Before this code can be run, you must run "Hobo_Organize" 1 time. Press 'Ctrl + Shift + O' to do this
'The purpose of this code is to separate the hobo data by day. Weekends and evenings will be removed.
'This will create smaller data sets, which allows for easier data manipulation

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Find the last row
     Lastrow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'Set the known parameters
    Dim days As Range
    Set days = Worksheets("Full Data Set").Range("C5:C" & Lastrow)
    Dim daychanges As String
    daychanges = 0


    'Maximum of 3 weeks of data, 21 different sheets
    Dim sheetnum(1 To 21) As Integer
        For i = 1 To 21
            sheetnum(i) = i
        Next i


'Loop through the day index (Col C), counting the number of day changes
    For Each cell In days
        If cell.Value <> cell.Offset(1).Value Then
            cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 37
            daychanges = daychanges + 1
        End If
    Next cell


'Add new sheets for each day and rename the sheets
    Sheets.Add after:=ActiveSheet
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Day 1"

    For i = 2 To daychanges
        Sheets.Add Before:=ActiveSheet
        ActiveSheet.Name = "Day " & sheetnum(i)
    Next i

    Sheets("Full Data Set").Select


'Sort the data by date
    For Each cell In days

            If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 37 Then
                cell.Select

                Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
                Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select

                Selection.Cut
                Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).Select
                ActiveSheet.Range("B2").Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
                ActiveSheet.Move Before:=Sheets("Full Data Set")


                Sheets("Full Data Set").Select
                Range("C4").Select
                Selection.End(xlDown).Select
                Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
                Set days = Selection

            End If

    Next cell

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

[Example of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOC3V.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd not pass through any cell coloring and use `RemoveDuplicates()` method of `Range` object as like follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub HOBO_Split_v2()
    Dim datesRng As Range, dataRng  As Range, cell As Range
    Dim iDay As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Full Data Set")
        Set datesRng = .Range("C5", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp)) '<--| set dates range
        Set dataRng = datesRng.offset(-1).Resize(datesRng.Rows.Count + 1, 6) '<--| set data range as dates one extended to next 5 columns
        With datesRng.offset(, .UsedRange.Columns.Count) '<--| use a helper column out of current used range
            .value = datesRng.value '<--|  copy dates value in helper column
            .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1) '<--|  remove duplicates and have only unique values in helper column

            For Each cell In .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers) '<--| iterate through remaining (unique) day values in helper column
                iDay = iDay + 1 '<--| update "current day" counter
                dataRng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Format(cell, "#.00") '<--| filter data by "current day", format the criteria as the actual column C cells format
                dataRng.offset(1).Resize(dataRng.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=SetWorkSheet(ThisWorkbook, "Day " & iDay).Range("B2") '<--| copy filtered data and paste the into "current day" corresponding sheet
            Next cell
           .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False '<--| remove autofilter
           .Clear '<--| clear helper column
        End With
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Function SetWorkSheet(wb As Workbook, SheetName As String) As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set SetWorkSheet = wb.Worksheets(SheetName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If SetWorkSheet Is Nothing Then
        Set SetWorkSheet = wb.Worksheets.Add(after:=wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count))
        SetWorkSheet.Name = SheetName
    Else
        SetWorkSheet.UsedRange.Clear '<--| clear preceeding values in already existent sheet
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The code works great. Cheers!

Comment: You're welcome. If I fullfilled your question please mark the answer as accepted. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to iterate over the list twice.  `GetWorkSheet` create the new worksheets for you if they don't exist and handle any errors.

```
Sub HOBO_Split_v2()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim cell As Range, days As Range
    Dim lFirstRow As Long, Lastrow As Long
    Dim SheetName As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    With Sheets("Full Data Set")

        Lastrow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        Set days = .Range("C5:C" & Lastrow)

        For Each cell In days
            If c.Text <> SheetName Or c.Row = Lastrow Then
                If lFirstRow > 0 Then

                    Set ws = getWorkSheet(SheetName)
                    .Range("A" & lFirstRow, "A" & cell.Row).EntireRow.Copy ws.Range("A1")

                End If
                SheetName = c.Text 
                lFirstRow = i
            End If
        Next

    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub


Function getWorkSheet(SheetName As String) As Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = Worksheets(SheetName)

    If ws Is Nothing Then
        Set ws = Worksheets.Add(after:=ActiveSheet)
        ws.Name = SheetName
    End If

    On Error GoTo 0
    Set getWorkSheet = ws
End Function
```